# Failed to package application when Android Manifest Portion is changed to

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I started a new test app, and downloaded a Holo Theme (by name JSTheme) from Android-holo-colors.com
And replaced the /res folder contents with the res folder in that downloaded zip file.

But when I replace the line in tiapp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

to this, then the compile is not happening. It shows then:
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.JSTheme"/>
        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

And when I restore back the lines above to same

Then the app gets compiled and everything works.

Am I doing something wrong?

And when I restore back the lines above to same

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Then the app gets compiled and everything works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the JSTheme.xml file is in the correct directory and format
   --> The correct directory for android themes is

> platform/android/res/values/JSTheme.xml

And the correct format should be like

```
<!-- Works for Titanium SDK 3.3.0 and later -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="LightDarkBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
    <style name="Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat"/>
</resources>
```

For more details about custom themes, check this [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes).

2. If this doesn't work, try this code in the `tiapp.xml`:

   ```
   <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <manifest>
           <application android:theme="@style/Theme.JSTheme"/>
       </manifest>
   </android>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Titanium doesn't support Holo themes anymore, make sure that you select 'appcompat' on the compatibility section of Android-holo-colors.com

Also, i found it best to use only lower case letters on the website and then capitalise the first letter in tiapp.xml

e.g.
on Android-holo-colors.com name it: jstheme

then in tiapp.xml: `<application android:theme="@style/Theme.Jstheme"/>`

Comment: But it says that - Min SDK supported by your app (if >= 11, will only generate holo resources). So if I am targeting >11 then the deafult generation would be of type Holo? Is there any other site which can provide good UI Sample App/Screens for Titanium Alloy?